# rails project#index don't display user projects - Many to Many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to create app like this : An user can create a project, and invite many members to this project. Right now, I try to display all projects created by the user with projects#index method on projects_controller.rb. But, on browser, on /projects links, I don't have any errors, and don't have projects.

Here is my code,

**projects_controller.rb** :

```
 def index
        @user = current_user
        @projects = @user.projects
    end

def create
        @project = Project.new(project_params)
        @project.user_id = current_user.id
        if @project.save
            flash[:success] = "successfully created project"
            redirect_to projects_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

Here is **models** (user, project, membership, invite) :

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'

    before_create :generate_token 
    before_save :check_user_existence

    def generate_token
        self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([self.project_id, Time.now, rand].join)
    end 

    def check_user_existence
        recipient = User.find_by_email(email)
        if recipient
            self.recipient_id = recipient.id
        end
    end

end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :projects, through: :memberships
    has_many :invitations, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
    has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
    has_many :invites
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
end
```

And here is the view where I want to display **user.projects** :

```
<div class="container">
    <h3> All your projects </h3>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <div class="project-card">
            <div class="card-title">
                <%= link_to project.title, project_path(project) %>
            </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Maybe you want to see the **schema** :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161211133001) do

  create_table "invites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "token"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "nb_team"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Thank you !

Comment: You don't find any projects listed in the page? Maybe the current user has no projects associated with him

Comment: @ArunKumar no I don't have any project listed, but in my create action in projects_controller.rb I have this line to enter the user_id on projects : `@project.user_id = current_user.id`

Comment: You can instead use `@project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)` This will populate the `user_id` field for you. Btw, Can you please explain what your issue is? If you don't find any projects, try to create a new one and see if it appears on the index page.

Comment: I try to create an other project, but nothing is listing ..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fix it by writing this :

```
def index
        @projects = Project.where(:user_id => current_user)
end
```

Maybe it will help !

Comment: You can better write it as `@projects = current_user.projects`